# Magento: checkout doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, magento, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, checkout

in the checkout process on http://www.dusseldorpafvalcontainer.nl/checkout/onepage/ stucks Internet Explorer at step 4. 
Visitors can select a bank, but the next step won't load.

Does anybody have an idea what the cause is of this problem?

Thanx

Comment: please describe your errors, make screenshots as often for SO users IE is a rarity that lives in a virtual machine

Comment: When you click the button, the loader next to it shows up en then it dissapears en nothing else happens.
It must jump to the next step, but in IE (8 and below) it doesn't.

Comment: We did that and we didn't get any wiser from fiddler